# Node.js for() loop value keep increasing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, web3js

I have setup an interval and loop for batch orders,

However the batch number in for loop keeps increasing.

Here is my code

```
const Web3 = require('web3')
const web3 = new Web3('ws://127.0.0.1:8546')

const accounts = require('./tps.json');

const quoteInterval = 5 * 1000;

const batch = new web3.BatchRequest();

const sendTransactions = async () => {
  try {
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      let account = accounts[i];
      const tx = web3.eth.sendTransaction.request(
        {
          from: web3.utils.toChecksumAddress("0xa00ce1f7fbf8298f4163ab23de8752942bdff98e"),
          to: web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(account),
          gas: 21000,
          gasPrice: 1000000000,
          value: 1
        }
      )
      batch.add(tx)
    }
    await batch.execute().then(console.log);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    process.exit(1)
  }
};

if (web3.eth.net.isListening()) {
  sendTransactions();

  setInterval(() => {
    sendTransactions();
  }, quoteInterval);
}
```

i value wasn't increasing, however, sendTransactions() function is doing like 2, 3, 4 or 5 times after every interval

Comment: Try re-instantiating (resetting) the batch request in the lambda passed into `setInterval`, before `sendTransactions`. Or rather just move `const batch = new web3.BatchRequest();`  into the `async` lambda, just before the `try` block.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you see that the value of `i` keep increasing? Did you put some `console.log` somewhere?

The following simplified version (with the same context operations of yours) is working fine:

```
async function asyncOperation(x) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(x) # this always outputs 0 < x < 5
            resolve()
        }, 50)
    })
}

const asyncFunction = async () => {
    allPromises = []
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        allPromises.push(asyncOperation(i))
    }
    await Promise.all(allPromises)
};

setInterval(() => asyncFunction(), 500)
```

Comment: i value wasn't increasing, however, sendTransactions() function is doing like 2, 3, 4 or 5 times after every interval

Answer (score 0):

```js
const quoteInterval = 5*1000;

const sendTransactions = async () => {
  try {
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    
    }
    
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    
  }
};


  sendTransactions();

  setInterval(() => {
    sendTransactions();
  }, quoteInterval);
```

As per the logic, It will not go above the 100

Comment: i value wasn't increasing, however, sendTransactions() function is doing like 2, 3, 4 or 5 times after every interval